# How to write a method that returns List<classname>?

Tags: java, list, return

So, in a test that i took few days ago we were supposed to make a method that returns a list, that contained all info about a class we had made before that.
The code looked like this:

```
public List<File> getall{
}
```

whereas File is the class that contains some variables and a `toString()` method.
So, what is a good way to write a method that returns this data type?

Comment: Take a look at the [Generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Answer (score 3):

I may be missing the point here, but it's really quite simple:

```
public List<File> getall() { 
    // create a List object to return
    List<File> returnValues = new ArrayList<>();

    // add File objects to returnValues
    ....
    // and return it
    return returnValues;
}
```

The nature of the class contained in the List is of no importance - however in this particular case you should be aware that [there's already a File class in the standard `java.io` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html), so `File` may not be the best name to give to a custom class...

Comment: that's about it. sorry for such a basic question

Comment: @user3460579 if it helped you that's fine, even basic questions should be answered if I understand the philosophy of this site correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

As you need to return a `List<File>` ,it depends on how you have implemented the File class.

```
public List<File> getAll() { 
    // create a List object to return
    List<File> listobj= new ArrayList<File>();
    //Do your stuff here you want to do and return that object

    return listobj;
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
public List<File> getAll() { 
    // create a List object 
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
    files.add(new file); // Keep doing this
    return files;
}
```